# google maps API Auto open infoWindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Code works perfectly. The issue I am seeing is that the maps Markers dont Auto-Open when first loaded.

Here is my code.
My first several attempts was using the "infoWindow.open(map,marker);" in both the For statement and proceeding the conclusion of the for statement.

I also have a codepen with current code. https://codepen.io/designsbycamaron/pen/evPWbL

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Asynchronously Load the map API 
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHlDHe3KZYAMqQIQoklenAKqi6jE2lxPA&callback=initMap";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});
function initMap() {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
            zoom: 10,
             mapTypeControl: false,
      draggable: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      scrollwheel: false,
      navigationControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("main_map"), mapOptions);

        //Create and open InfoWindow.
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i];
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });

            //Attach click event to the marker.
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                    infoWindow.setContent("<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + data.description + "</div>");

                });

            })(marker, data);

        }
        infoWindow.open(map,marker);
    }
```

Comment: At the moment you are opening the infoWindow on page load, with no content, and then setting the content of that infoWindow to something. What is your desired result? I'd say you want to move the infoWindow to the correct location and set content to the new content??

Comment: Or do you want an infoWindow for each marker, and for them to auto open?

Comment: See that is what occurs is that the infoWindow opens without content, but it only opens one, and it will only open once.. Frustration... The desired outcome is that the window open for each location, with each locations content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an infoWindow for each marker. Store them in an array. Open them all at the start. There is also an event listener that opens the correct one when clicked and closes the other. Not sure what you wanted to do on maker click...

[Link to forked codepen here](https://codepen.io/motionimaging/pen/vxQNmX)

```
var markers = [{"title": "City A","lat": "44.6299425","lng": "-123.0813560","description": "lore lipsum epsum ipsum", "deptID":"29","provID":"119"},{"title": "City B","lat": "44.5671365","lng": "-123.2745664","description": "lore lipsum epsum ipsum", "deptID":"28","provID":"120"}];
jQuery(function($) {
  // Asynchronously Load the map API 
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCHlDHe3KZYAMqQIQoklenAKqi6jE2lxPA&callback=initMap";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
});

var markersList = [];

function initMap() {

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    draggable: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("main_map"), mapOptions);

  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

    var data = markers[i];

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: data.title
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "<div style = 'width:200px;min-height:40px'>" + markers[i].description + "</div>"
    });

    marker.infobox = infowindow;

    markersList.push(marker);

    //Attach click event to the marker.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {

        console.log(i);

        // Close all other infoboxes
        for (var j = 0; j < markersList.length; j++) {
          markersList[j].infobox.close(map);
        }

        // Open correct info box
        markersList[i].infobox.open(map, markersList[i]);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }

  // Open all on page load
  for (var j = 0; j < markersList.length; j++) {
    markersList[j].infobox.open(map, markersList[j]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. The storing in an array and then for is an approach I had not thought of.. Im going to give it a try.

Comment: @Cam you should be able to just drop that code in and it'll work